# denote rails model if not stored in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a specific naming convention for a model that will not be stored in the database?  For example, i have a schedule which will be a model, but will not be in the database because it is just a data structure.  In other words it will not extend ActiveRecord::Base?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I view this as an internal implementation detail; I wouldn't reflect it in the name, because other models that are interacting with a given model should not know or care whether it is persisted.  And your requirements could change later and it would become persisted.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a class in the Model that doesn't persist to the database than just don't inherit ActiveRecord::Base

e.g

```
class SomeClass 

end
```

The class definition is still saved to the file some_class.rb in the model directory

As for naming convention. Well a Model class is a Model class, it doesn't matter if it persists to the database, or some place else, or not at all. I see no need for any special naming convention.

Your Controller and Views should just interact with the your Model objects without being concerned about that object's underlying persistence mechanism. That's one of the main advantages of Model-View-Controller ... The Controller and View need not be concerned with the inner working on the Model objects. So neither should your naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to make non-active record models to inherit from the NonActiveRecordModel class (or something like that, which you can define yourself).  The abstract NonActiveRecordModel class can have common behavior that is used by all of your non-active record models, such as validations via validatable gem, etc.